# Displaying a list returned from a method on a Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, commandbutton, action, repeat, outputpanel

I've tried various iterations but this is what I have right now. This is the main code from VF Page:

```
                    <div>
                <h3>Search Groups</h3>
                 <apex:form >
                  <apex:inputText id="groupName" list="{!listOfStrings}" value="{!groupname}"/>
                  <apex:commandButton value="Submit" reRender="wrapper" action="{!retrieveGroupMembers}"/>

                 </apex:form>
            </div>
        <apex:pageblock >

            <apex:outputPanel id="wrapper">
                         <apex:repeat value="{!PGM}" var="u">
                        <div class="view view-seventh">
                            <!--<img src="{!u.FullPhotoUrl}" />-->
                            <div class="mask">
                                <h2>{!u.users.CompanyName}</h2>

                                <a href="#" class="info">Read More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                          </apex:repeat>                    

                </apex:outputPanel>
```

The Apex:

```
    public string groupName{get;set;}
public User[] users{get;set;}
public List<PublicGroupsMembers> PGM {get; set;}

public void retrieveGroupMembers(){
    // Get the users.
    PublicGroupsMembers pgm = new PublicGroupsMembers();
    List<PublicGroupsMembers> lPGM = new List<PublicGroupsMembers>();
    users = [Select AboutMe,FirstName,LastName,AccountId,IsActive,CompanyName,ContactId,Department,Email,ManagerId,Phone,ProfileId,UserRoleId,Title,SmallPhotoUrl,FullPhotoUrl,Id,UserType,Username FROM User WHERE Id IN (SELECT UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE Group.Name IN (:groupName))];
    for(user u:users){
        pgm.users = u;
        pgm.SmallPhotoUrl = u.SmallPhotoUrl;
        pgm.FullPhotoUrl = u.FullPhotoUrl;
        PGM = pgm;
     }

}

public class PublicGroupsMembers{
    public User users;
    public string SmallPhotoUrl;
    public string FullPhotoUrl;
}
```

if I use "{!users}" instead of "{!PGM}" it will work. Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Apex is a case-insensitive language. The identifiers `pgm` and `PGM` are the same as far as the compiler is concerned. In addition, there is a key logical error in the code populating this variable. Let's look at what's happening here:

```
PublicGroupsMembers pgm = new PublicGroupsMembers();
```

This local variable shadows the instance variable `PGM`. You now cannot access the instance variable while this local is in scope without an explicit `this` reference.

```
List<PublicGroupsMembers> lPGM = new List<PublicGroupsMembers>();
```

You don't use this at all, and you actually don't need it.

```
for(user u:users){
    pgm.users = u;
    pgm.SmallPhotoUrl = u.SmallPhotoUrl;
    pgm.FullPhotoUrl = u.FullPhotoUrl;
    PGM = pgm;
```

This line assigns `pgm` to itself. Note that `pgm` is a single `PublicGroupsMembers` instance, not a `List<PublicGroupsMembers>`. It looks like what you meant to do was

```
lPGM.add(pgm);
```

However, all you need to do is initialize `PGM` - the instance variable, the list - with an empty list when you start, call your single `PublicGroupsMembers` something else like `currentPublicGroupMember`, and then do

```
PGM.add(currentPublicGroupMember);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I made the changes that you have suggested. In debug PGM has the data in it. The VF page is still not displaying my data and it still looks the same as above but I uncommented out FullPhotoUrl.

Comment: I figured it out. I had to change PublicGroupsMembers to be this:         public User lusers{get; set;}
        public string SmallPhotoUrl{get; set;}
        public string FullPhotoUrl{get; set;}